# El host virtual de laragon tarda mucho en cargar

Tags: web, virtualhost, laragon

Yo utilizo laragon como entorno de desarrollo, y un amigo tambien quiso probarlo pero tiene el problema de que al acceder a sus proyectos por le vistual host ("nombre del proyecto".test) no carga en su navegador, tiene que pasar como un minuto para que recien se cargue el hmtl, en mi caso hago proyectos con laravel y siempre me ha funcionado sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.